# Select with join outputs not exact match [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, select, join

Can anyone explain why query:

```
select rma.id, history_transactions.reference 
from history_transactions 
join rma on history_transactions.reference = rma.id
```

Returns:

```
id     | reference
100144 |    100144
102299 |    102299a
100316 |    100316AFEN1
```

Can't get it to show only 100% matched, so only first row. If someone can explain why it happens it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently rma.id column is numeric (integer), while the reference field is textual, since it contains text as well.

As MySQL documentation on [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) describes, if you compare text with number, the comparison is one as floating point numbers, meaning that the reference field is converted to a number.

MySQL converts a string to number by evaluating its characters left to right, as long as the charters can be interpreted as a number. If it encounters a character that cannot be evaluated as a number, then MySQL stops the evaluation and returns the previous characters as the numeric value.

In case of the 2nd record, the letter `a` is the 1st character that cannot be evaluated as number, therefore the numeric value of `'102299a'` string is `102299`. The same logic applies to the 3rd record.

To force MySQL to return exact matches only, explicitly convert `rma.id` to string using [cast() or convert()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) functions in the query. This way the comparison would be done as strings, not as floating point numbers.

Comment: thanks for explanations, cast(rma.id as char) did the job!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is most probably *implicit type conversion*. My guess is that `id` field is of `integer` type, whereas `reference` field is of `varchar` type. Hence, when comparing MySQL converts `varchar` to a number. So, e.g. value `'10299a'`  is converted to `10299` and is *then* compared to the corresponding value of `id` field.

[**Live demo of the issue**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79ee28/1)

Comment: how can i 100% match it then?

Comment: MySQL converts the string to floating point number, not to int!

Comment: @arti You have to cast `id` to `varchar`.

Comment: @Shadow Thank you for the remark, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit datatype conversion.

I suspect the `id` column is declared as numeric datatype. Most likely `INT`.

The `reference` column is declared as character type. Most likely `VARCHAR`.

To do the equality comparison, MySQL can't compare a "string" with a "number".

So MySQL is implicitly doing a conversion of the string value into a number, and then doing the comparison of the numeric values.

Other databases would throw an error given a string that isn't a valid number.

But MySQL allows the conversion (without error or warning.)

As a demonstration, these expressions cause MySQL to do implicit conversion of a string to a number:

```
SELECT '123ABC' + 0 
     , '4D5E6F' + 0 
     , 'G7H8I9' + 0
```

---

Given your values, for example

```
SELECT '100316AFEN1' + 0
```

We see that MySQL returns a numeric value of 100316 which it uses to compare.

---